# Force unlocking a reentrant lock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, reentrancy

I have a reentrant lock which I am wrapping in a customized class for my own needs. However due to the nature of the application a thread holding the lock to the reentrant lock gets stuck (external failures) and fails to release the reentrant lock.

I am wondering if there is a method to explicitly unlock the reentrant lock? I know the API for Reentrant lock does not have such a method - however I was thinking of introducing a timer task which will unlock the Reentrant lock after a set period of time OR kill the thread which holds the reentrant lock.

Any other suggestions in trying to force unlock my reentrant lock? My solutions are pretty thus I ask.

Comment: Do you have some sample code??  All locks should be wrapped in `try/catch/finally` blocks, within the final section, you should release any locks you currently hold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of unlocking externally, I would execute the blocking code in a separate thread and have it timeout

something like this

```
Future<MyTask>future = taskExecutor.submit(myTask)
try {
    future.get(5,TimeUnit.Seconds);
    ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        future.cancel(true); // attempt to interupt the thread
        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Comment: I eventually went with this solution :)

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, any lock should be wrapped around a `try/finally` block to ensure that the lock is released if something goes wrong

```
_lock.lock(); // will wait until this thread gets the lock
try
{
    // critical section
}
finally
{
    //releasing the lock so that other threads can get notifies
    _lock.unlock();
}
```

This is demonstrated in the [Lock Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html) trail

Comment: I appreciate the response, however, I am looking for force unlock the "_lock" as per your example. Agreed that the holder should unlock the lock it holds, however, the holder thread occasionally goes into a funky state due to some external dependency and never gives up the lock. Unless I somehow kill the thread OR force unlock "_lock" no other thread will progress forward which is why I was contemplating a force unlock mechanism.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve what you want. This would actually defeat the purpose of the lock

Comment: In some regard I totally agree with you - but essentially what I am looking for is a intelligent way to get out of states where the application fails to progress any further due to external failures and fails to give up locks. Btw, _lock.unlock() also throws a IllegalMontiorStateException, should the call to unlock() be also wrapped in a try/catch? Is there a closeQuietly() equivalent to for lock unlocks()?

Comment: *should the call to unlock() be also wrapped*, yes, you are right, it should be wrapped in a try/catch (unless you want to throw it instead).  The best solution I can think of (which really is a hack), is to provide a method into the way-world thread that would allow you to unlock the lock

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? It's nice to learn from other people's perspective